# MouseOver on a button triggered only on its bottom

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've left all my windows with Style=None, and put this usercontrol on top-right corner of it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SayRecep.Controls.WindowControls"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="27" d:DesignWidth="80">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="WindowControlButton">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#BBBBBB" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="Blue" Width="20" Height="16">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,9,6,0">
        <Button ToolTip="Minimize" Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" Click="Button_Click">
            <Button.Content>
                <Grid Width="12" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                    <Path Data="M0,1 L4,1 Z" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                          Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2"  />
                </Grid>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <Grid  MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">
            <Button x:Name="Restore" ToolTip="Restore" Click="Restore_Click" Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" Visibility="Visible">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Grid UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,.5,.5">
                        <Path Margin="0,0,0,0" Data="M2,0 L8,0 L8,6 M0,3 L6,3 M0,2 L6,2 L6,8 L0,8 Z" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                              Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"  />
                    </Grid>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Maximize" ToolTip="Maximize" Click="Maximize_Click" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" >
                <Button.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Data="M0,1 L9,1 L9,8 L0,8 Z" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2"  />
                    </Grid>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Button ToolTip="Close" Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" Click="Button_Click_1" >
            <Button.Content>
                <Grid Width="12" Height="12" >
                    <Path Data="M0,0 L14,14 M0,14 L14,0" Stretch="Fill"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                              Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2.25"  />
                </Grid>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I'm using these for Mimimize, Restore/Maximize and Close the Window.

The problem is that the mouse identifies the button only bottom half of it.

Does'nt raise Click, MouseOver or wont even show the Tooltip from its top half.

In the Template you can see a blue border, Actually that wasn't there before. I kept that to analyse the problem thinking making it transparent might solve. But didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style works now

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="WindowControlButton">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#BBBBBB" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```